# How to properly calculate the order of growth of an exponential algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading SICP, and I'm a little bit confuse about this statement:

> Consider the problem of computing the exponential of a given number.
>   We would like a procedure that takes as arguments a base b and a
>   positive integer exponent n and computes b n . One way to do this is
>   via the recursive definition
>
> ```
> b n = b ⋅ b n − 1 ,
> b 0 = 1
> ```
>
> which translates readily into the procedure
>
> ```
> (define (expt b n)
>   (if (= n 0) 
>       1 
>       (* b (expt b (- n 1)))))
> ```
>
> This is a linear recursive process, which requires Θ ( n ) steps and Θ
>   ( n ) space.

I did a tree illustrating the process generated by the procedure:

```
(expt 2 2)
|
|
|
(expt 2 1)
```

Which makes the statement "This is a linear recursive process, which requires Θ ( n ) steps and Θ ( n ) space." true. But when I use a substitution model, it seems that requires 0 ( n ^ 2) steps and space:

```
(expt 2 2)
    (* 2 (expt 2 1))
    (* 2 2)
4
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer we assume the arithmetic model of computation, in which each arithmetic operation has cost 1.

The question has bad notation. Define function `expt b n` to compute `b^n` as:

```
expt b 0 = 1
expt b n = b ⋅ expt b (n − 1)
```

Computing `expt b n` requires computing `n-1`, computing `expt b (n-1)`, and multiplying that expression by `b`. So the cost of `expt b n` is $2 +$ the cost of `expt b (n-1)`. `expt b 0` has cost 0.

Putting the above together, we see the cost of `exp b n` is $2 +$ the cost of `exp b (n-1)`, $= 4 +$ the cost of `exp b (n-2)`, $\ldots$, $= 2n +$ the cost of `exp b 0`, $= 2n$.